# Can you provide a highcharts_stock example written in python with multiple line charts?

Tags: python, highcharts, stock

Can you point me to an example written in python that uses the latest version of highchart_stock 1.5.0 (as installed from pypi) for python and includes 2 series showing the closing price of two stocks displayed as line charts?

I've tried the documentation, a number of examples, and highchart's chatgtp help.  I've had various degrees of partial success because of outdated examples which stop me from piecing the right solution together.

Comment: The right way to use this web site is to post the code you have, and explain what isn't working.

Comment: tim-roberts - I don't disagree. There are so many issues with highcharts python ...  Including directing people to post here because they monitor and answer question.  Even the stack-overflow tag they tell people to use, "highcharts-for-python", doesn't exist.  Post code I have?  I wish ... I just have their nonfunctional code.  If no-one from highcharts responds, I may delete the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Full Disclosure: I'm the primary author of Highcharts for Python*

I'm sorry that you're having trouble with Highcharts Stock for Python. There's a tutorial that you may find helpful linked [here](https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/tutorials/series.html). Note that the tutorial is written for Highcharts Core, but the exact same code will work in Highcharts Stock (just change your import statements to import from `highcharts_stock` rather than `highcharts_core`).

Furthermore, you can find numerous working examples of Highcharts Stock visualizations in our examples repo linked here: https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-for-python-demos

Note that Binder has recently been having some performance issues, so you may want to clone the repo to review the Jupyter Notebooks locally to see how the visualizations render.

That being said, below you will find a modified example from the demo repo showing two line series in Highcharts Stock showing some made-up closing price data:

```
from highcharts_stock.chart import Chart
from highcharts_stock.options.series.area import LineSeries
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':[
        dt.datetime(2023,1,1), 
        dt.datetime(2023,1,2), 
        dt.datetime(2023,1,3), 
        dt.datetime(2023,1,4)
    ], 
    'closing1': [10,20,15,18], 
    'closing2': [12, 31, 45, 21]
})

line_series_1 = LineSeries.from_pandas(df,
                                       property_map = {
                                           'x': 'date',
                                           'y': 'closing1'
                                       })
line_series_2 = LineSeries.from_pandas(df,
                                       property_map = {
                                           'x': 'date',
                                           'y': 'closing2'
                                       })

my_chart = Chart(container = 'my_container', 
                 options = {
                     'title' : {
                         'text': 'Ticker'
                     },
                     'x_axis' : {
                         'type': 'datetime',
                         'title': {
                             'text': 'Date'
                         }
                     }, 
                     'y_axis' : {
                         'title': {
                             'text': 'Closing Price'
                         }
                     },
                     'series' : [line_series_1, line_series_2]
                 }
                )
```

when the chart gets serialized to JS using the `.to_js_literal()` method, it produces the JS code shown in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/highchartspython/u31Ljrte/

Obviously, this toy example is just a toy. The data generated in the dataframe is completely made-up data, and the chart does not feature any formatting or significant interactivity. But nevertheless, I hope you find it helpful.

And in the meantime, thanks for the feedback. We're hard at work to improve things with some coming releases of Highcharts for Python.

Comment: Chris,  Thank you for the example.  I appreciate you and others are hard at work improving the framework and python integration.  I've run into a number of issues including out-of-date examples, documentation issues, multiples sources of conflicting "truth", confusion on where to spend time for help, and performance problems with the python module specifically to name a few.  I can provide you a list if you would find it helpful.  I can also delete this post as it does not conform to the community standards as tim-roberts pointed out.  Let me know what is helpful to you.